# Catch new hundred number in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, modulo

I got a list of bus number in my database. Sample here :

```
    route_id,route_short_name,route_long_name,route_type,route_color,route_text_color
    1,1,Victoria / Churchill,3,A32638,FFFFFF
    2,2,Tiffin / St-Georges,3,A32638,FFFFFF
    99,99,Saint-Bruno,3,A32638,FFFFFF
    100,100,Ile-Des-Soeurs,3,A32638,FFFFFF
    106,106,Secteur B / Victoria,3,A32638,FFFFFF
    199,199,Seigneurial / Grand Boulevard,3,A32638,FFFFFF
    818,T18,Taxi - Aéroport,3,A32638,FFFFFF
    893,T93,Taxi - De Mortagne - Du Boisé - Ch. De Touraine,3,A32638,FFFFFF
```

We will be working with route_id (first column).

Here is my question. How can I catch a new hundred ? The expected results from above will be

```
    1 to 99
    100 to 199
    818 to 893
```

I am almost always finding the answer to my question but this time.. I really don't. I did this but this ain't working well :

```
# Creating the array
$Routes = array();
$Quick = array();

# Array launching
$F_D = -1;
$i=0;
while($Assoc_Routes = mysql_fetch_assoc($Query_Routes)){
    # Array
    $Routes[] = $Assoc_Routes;

    $Digit_Length = strlen($Assoc_Routes['route_short_name']);
    switch($Digit_Length){
        case 1 : $Digit = '00'.$Assoc_Routes['route_id'][0]; break;
        case 2 : $Digit = '0'.$Assoc_Routes['route_id'][0]; break;
        default: $Digit = $Assoc_Routes['route_id'][0]; break;
    }

    if($Digit[0] != $F_D){
        # Count
        $i++;

                    # Avoid the first one
        if($i > 1){
            $Quick[$i-1]['g'].= ' à '.($Assoc_Routes['route_id']-1);
        }
        $Quick[$i] = array('g' => 'Groupement '.$Assoc_Routes['route_id']);
    }
    $F_D = $Digit[0];
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new variable that tracks which group you are in:

```
$currentGroup = 0;
$groupSize = 100;
```

Then compare your route_id to the currentGroup to see if it's within its groupSize:

```
if ($Assoc_Routes['route_id'] >= $currentGroup+$groupSize && $groupSize != 0) 
{
    //update the value for your currentGroup
    $currentGroup = floor($Assoc_Routes['route_id']/$groupSize)*$groupSize;
}
```

Comment: You should cast as int, truncate, or floor it. Round will act wrong at 50's

Comment: @Mikhail Right you are-- I floored it.  BTW, nice answer, very elegant.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0Zz3qZpL .. Code updated with comment. Working very well. Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in what form you want the output to be, but here's the approach I'd take:

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_object...
  $index = floor($r->route_id / 100);

  $groups[$index][] = $r;
```